# Compute sup norm of sequence of functions.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, maxima-minima, sequence-of-function

> Consider the operator $T: C^2[0,1] \subset C^1[0,1] \to C^1[0,1]$ defined by $Tf=f'+f''$.
> Compute $\| T e^{-nx } \|_{\infty }$ and $\| T x^n \|_{\infty }$.

My attempt.

First I tried to compute $\| e^{-nx } \|_{\infty } $ and $\| x^n \|_{\infty } $.
We have $$\| e^{-nx } \|_{\infty } =\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R} } |e^{-nx} |$$
We find the derivative of $|e^{-nx} |$
which is $-ne^{-nx} $, and $$-ne^{-nx}  =0 \implies n=0$$
So $$\| e^{-nx } \|_{\infty }=1$$

Similarly for $$\| x^n \|_{\infty } =\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R} } |x^n |$$
So the derivative is $|nx^{n-1} |$ which is $0$ for $n=0$
Hence, $$\| x^n \|_{\infty }=1.$$

Now for $\| T e^{-nx } \|_{\infty }$, we have $$\| Te^{-nx} \|_{\infty } =\| -ne^{-nx} +n^2 e^{-nx} \|_{\infty } =\| (n(n-1)) e^{-nx} \|_{\infty } =-n+n^2$$
therefore $\| e^{-nx } \|_{\infty } =-n+n^2$.

For $\| T x^n \|_{\infty }$ we have
$$\| Tx^n \|_{\infty } =\| nx^{n-1} +n(n-1)x^{n-2} \| \leq n \| x^{n-1} \|_{\infty } +n(n-1) \| x^{n-2} \|_{\infty }=n+n(n-1).$$

Is this correct?
I think there's something wrong with my computation for $\|Tx^n \|_{\infty }$ because if I used the derivative to find Maxima of $| T x^n |$ I would get $| n(n-1) x^{n-2}-n(n-1)(n-2) | =0$
and it seems that either $n=0$ or $n=1$ or $x=0$ or $x=n-2$, in each case I get different extrema.

Can you explain what is wrong with my computation?

Comment: OK i understand now. The derivative of $|e^{cx}|=e^{cx}$ is $c e^{cx}$ which is not $|ce^{-cx}|$

Comment: If you want to compute the exact value of $\|Tx^n\|_\infty,$ you cannot use an inequality like triangle inequality in the middle. What you have gotten is an upper bound for $\|Tx^n\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: I see, so to compute $\| Tx^n \|$ should I use the derivative and find it's zeroes?

Comment: yes, that should work

Comment: Is the norm for $\| Te^{-nx} \|$ I computed, correct?

Comment: Yes, that one is right.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help.